# C# stream is empty after using

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a simple method takes file.InputStream

The problem is when i use the below method for the first time it worked great but when i use it for second time inputStream is empty

```
public static MemoryStream ConvertImageAsStream(Stream inputStream,int widthPercentage,int heightPercentage)
{
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    outputStream.Position = 0;
    inputStream.Position = 0;
    if (inputStream.Length > 0)
    {
        ImageJob imageJob = new ImageJob(inputStream, outputStream, imageResizeSettings);
        imageJob.Instructions.AutoRotate = true;
        imageJob.Build();
    }
    return outputStream;
}
```

This works:

```
var imageOutputStream = ConvertImageAsStream(file.InputStream, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

This doesn't work:

```
var thumbnailOutputStream = ConvertImageAsStream(file.InputStream, thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight);
```

Comment: You might have to call `.Seek()` to rewind back to the beginning..

Comment: This is unclear what your asking. Add more detail for people to respond with proper answers.

Comment: Perhaps, `ImageJob` sets pointer to the end of `file.InputStream`. First time it's OK, but second time the pointer is at the end of the stream. Show off `ImageJob` method.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, Thank you for your help , actually i tried stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); and the problem didn't solved

Comment: @JohnyL, Thank you so much for your help and effort. Can you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Show your `ImageJob` method

Comment: Please learn to think like a programmer. Don't use terms like *this doesn't work*. What doesn't work? What did you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: It sounds like `using` block closed the stream, which is exactly what it is designed to do.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't see a using-block.  I think the title is actually meant to convey they "used" it.

Comment: @LarsTech It will be there, hidden in the `ImageJob` class, as sure as the sun rose this morning.

Comment: If the stream gets disposed, you can't tell if it's empty or not, because `MemoryStream.Length` throws `ObjectDisposedException.` However, you can inspect it in the debugger, and find that, in fact, is not empty, because `Dispose()` does not do anything except mark itself closed; the internal buffer and accounting data remain intact.